# Add checkboxlist item onclick of another checkbox

Tags: asp.net, ajax, checkboxlist

I'm just wondering if there's a way to add a new checkbox item to an existing asp:checkboxlist  control, when another checkbox is checked, without having to do a full postback of the page.  Whether it's with javascript, jquery, ajax.  Just wondering how (if at all) I can do something like this.

I've been doing some research and it appears I can do a partial postback using an asp:UpdatePanel.  I've never used one of these before.  Does anyone have an example of how they can be used?  Here's what I have, but it's still doing a full postback

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <tr>
           <td width="50%">
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkEnglish" Font-Bold="true" TextAlign="Right" Text=" English" />
           </td>
           <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTopLanguages">
           <td rowspan="3" valign="top">
               <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkTopLanguages" CssClass="cb chkTopLangs" TextAlign="Right" runat="server" />
               <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOtherLanguages" onkeyup="SetButtonStatus(this)" onclick="return clearLanguageSearchText()" Text="Other Languages..."></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddLang" Text="Add" OnClientClick="return CopyOtherLangs()" Enabled="false" /><br /><br />
               <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkManyOtherLanguages" CssClass="cb" Font-Bold="true" Text="Many other languages" />
               <cc3:AutoCompleteExtender ID="aceSearch" runat="server" MinimumPrefixLength="1" TargetControlID="txtOtherLanguages"
                                                                                        ServicePath="~/controls/wsCommunity.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetLanguageCompletionList"></cc3:AutoCompleteExtender>
           </td>
           </asp:Panel>
         </tr>
        </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Building off Adils answer...to add a checkbox on check of another one, you can use:

```
$(".classOfCheckboxList").change(function() {
    $(this).append("<input type='checkbox' id='newbox' class='currentclass' value='someval' />");
});
```

As Adil said, this new dynamically added box wont be accessible in the code-behind.